# Colocar pontuação em tempo real em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um trabalho da escola, que é para amanhã, e ele já está pronto, é o famoso jogo 'Snake' em javascript e html, porém hj eu pensei em colocar a pontuação do jogador em tempo real no jogo. Já tentei várias coisas mas só aparece 'Pontuação: 0' independente de quantas maçãs vc tenha comido. 
É possível fazer isso em javascript? Se sim, como faço isso?

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event){
  pegadirecao(event.keyCode);
}

tabuleiro="<table align=center border=1>";
for (x=0;x<10;x++)
{ tabuleiro+="<tr>";
 for(y=0;y<10;y++)
 {tabuleiro+="<td id=td"+x+"_"+y+" style='width:30px; height:30px;'> </td>";
 }
tabuleiro+="</tr>";
}
tabuleiro+="</table>";
document.getElementById('principal').innerHTML=tabuleiro;

cobra=[[5,0]];
direcao=2;
vivo=true;
function desenhapedaco(x,y)
{
 document.getElementById('td'+x+'_'+y).style.background="#333333";
}
function apagapedaco(x,y)
{
 document.getElementById('td'+x+'_'+y).style.background="#ffffff";
}
function geramaca()
{ mx=parseInt(Math.random()*10)
 my=parseInt(Math.random()*10)
 document.getElementById('td'+mx+'_'+my).style.background="#ff3333";
}

function anda()
{ apagapedaco(cobra[cobra.length-1][0], cobra[cobra.length-1][1]);
 if(mx==cobra[0][0]&&my==cobra[0][1])
 {
 geramaca();
 cobra[cobra.length]=[10,10];
 }
  for(x=cobra.length-1;x>0;x--)
  { cobra[x][0]=cobra[x-1][0];
   cobra[x][1]=cobra[x-1][1];
  }
 if(direcao==0)cobra[0][1]--;
 if(direcao==1)cobra[0][0]--;
 if(direcao==2)cobra[0][1]++;
 if(direcao==3)cobra[0][0]++;
 if(cobra[0][0]<0||cobra[0][1]<0||cobra[0][0]>9||cobra[0][1]>9)
 {vivo=false;
 }
 for(x=1;x<cobra.length;x++)
 {if(cobra[x][0]==cobra[0][0]&&cobra[x][1]==cobra[0][1])vivo=false;
 }
 if(vivo)
 {
 desenhapedaco(cobra[0][0],cobra[0][1]);
 setTimeout('anda();', 300);
 }
 else
 {alert('Você perdeu, seu otario.\nVocê pegou '+(cobra.length-1)+' maçãs');
 }
}
geramaca();
anda();
function pegadirecao(tecla)
{ //alert(tecla);
 if(tecla==37) direcao=0;
 if(tecla==38) direcao=1;
 if(tecla==39) direcao=2;
 if(tecla==40) direcao=3;
}
document.write('Pontuação: \n'+(cobra.length-1)+' Maçãs!');
```

```html
<div id=principal></div>
<h1>
```

Comment: É possível sim, apenas criando um contador no evento que ele "pega" a maça.

Comment: Poste o código.

Comment: Sem o código fica difícil ajudar, mas claro que é possível.

Comment: Já coloquei o código no post. Se puderem me ajudar, eu agradeceria muito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes juntar um novo elemento no HTML:

```
<div id="pontuacao"></div>
```

e depois atualizar via JavaScript com:

```
var infoPontos = document.getElementById('pontuacao');
function pontuou() {
    infoPontos.innerHTML = 'Pontuação: \n' + (cobra.length - 1) + ' Maçãs!';
}
```

inserido aqui:

```
if (mx == cobra[0][0] && my == cobra[0][1]) {
    geramaca();
    cobra[cobra.length] = [10, 10];
    pontuou(); // <---------------------- aqui e se quiseres uma vez no inicio do script tb
}
```

**O resultado seria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/31az4hxo/**

## Sugestão:

Não mistures HTML e/ou CSS no JavaScript, usa a API do JavaScript para criar elementos do DOM, e classes de CSS para manipular cores.

**Usa antes algo parecido com: http://jsfiddle.net/31az4hxo/1/**. Uma outra vantagem desta versão que coloco é que guarda os elementos na memória, em vez de usar `document.getElementById`, multiplas vezes a cada 300ms

Comment: Sergio, muito obrigado! Já havia aprendido várias coisas em javascript com esse trabalho, e agora aprendi mais uma que com certeza eu vou usar bastante.

Comment: @J.Gaidzinski dá uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/31az4hxo/1/ eu faria assim para não misturar HTML ou CSS no JavaScript